# git log for a commit id and the 10 commits AFTER it

Tags: git, logging

i'm looking for a list of commits ending with a certain commit id and starting with the commit 10 commits above (newer than) it. Basically i want to find out what happened immediately after a certain commit that might be related to it.

i could do

```
git log <mycommitid>..HEAD
```

but that lists thousands of commits, i just want 10

i want to do something like the following, but that's not legal syntax

```
git log mycommitid^-10..mycommitid
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shell command that will give you what you want:

```bash
git log -n 10 "$(git rev-list --reverse <commit id>~.. |head -10 |tail -1)"
```

The subshell in this case expands to the commit 10 commits in the future from `<commit id>`, so it's *actually* a look backwards starting from *that* commit. Add the `--reverse` argument onto `log` to view those commits in reverse order, oldest to newest.

Unfortunately, in Git's syntax for specifying [commit ranges](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) there is no operator for going forward in history. You only have `~` and `^` which refer to parent or ancestor commits. It's going to have to be a subshell or nothing.

Here's an alternate command that will give the diff as well as the commit log.

```bash
git show $(git rev-list --reverse <commit id>~.. |head -10)
```

*(The reason I had to use `|head` here is because `git rev-list --reverse -n 10 <commit range>` gives the 10 latest commits in the range, meaning it applies the limiter BEFORE the reversal, which is likely a bug.)*

Comment: I think "Unfortunately" is poor choice of words. This is a trivially obvious consequence of what Git is.

Comment: @matt No, software should [*Do What I Mean*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM). The fact I could do it with a workaround means it *could* do it, it just doesn't choose to. I stand by my wording that it's unfortunate it doesn't.

Comment: That's a good argument: basically you're saying "If I can do it, why can't Git do it for me?"